# my program prints the list joined instead of adding it's elements

Tags: python, list, function

I was requested to write a function called summer which gets a list and returns its sum but **only if** all the elements in the list are of the same type. 
For example if:

```
summer(['a','b','c'])
```

the result will be:

```
abc
```

if

```
summer (['True','False','True'])
```

the result will be:

```
2
```

**but**
if

```
summer (['a','1','k'])
```

it will print the elements are not of the same type.

Here's my code:

```
def summer(lst):
    summary=0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if i==0:
            summary=lst[0]
        else:
            summary+=lst[i]
    return summary
lst=input("Insert list ")
lst=lst.split(',')
print(summer(lst))
```

My code just joins everything:

if the input is `True, False` the printing is `TrueFalse`

please help me fix it, thank you!

Comment: The rule is inconcise. `'a', 'b', 'c'` none of these are the same? Or do you mean actual `type(val)`? if so you've misspelled `'True', 'False', 'True'` and it should be `True, False, True` without the quotations.

Comment: the actual type: 'a', 'b','c' are all string 'True', 'False', 'True' are all boolean

Comment: There's nothing in your `summer()` function that checks whether the values are the same type.

Comment: `input()` always returns a string, and `lst.split()` always returns a list of strings. There's nothing in your code that tries to convert numeric strings to numbers, boolean strings to booleans, etc.

Comment: @Daniel.Agranat No, `'True'` is not a boolean, not in programming terms. That's still a string. You're thinking of `True` which is a boolean. Same goes for `'1'`, it's also a string, **not** a number. Programatically that is. I as a human, can see that it's a number. That's why python has `'1'.isdigit()` for instance.

Comment: There's also the issue of, in one scenario, it prints the combined text `abc`, but in another instance, it prints the number of occurrences. What constraints are there?

Comment: @Barmar How should I do it?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will turn a string like `"foo,bar"` into a list of strings, but `"1,2"` into a list of integers and `"True,False"` into a list of booleans. You'll need to write your own function that does this. You could use `ast.literal_eval()`, and if it throws an error return the value as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you'll have to do is to check each element's type.

So over your `if/else` condition within the `for` loop, consider to check if all elements are of the same type. Something like:

```
for item in lst:
    if (type(item) != lst[0]):
         break;
```

If I correctly understood your problem, only if there's no difference among all the elements then the desired operation should be performed.

I hope that it can be clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are trying to do or somewhat close.

```
def summer(lst):
    summary=0
    if all(isinstance(i,int) for i in lst):
        return sum(lst)
    if all(isinstance(i,str) for i in lst):
        return ''.join(lst)
    else:
        return 'Elements not the same'
summer([True,False,True])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def summer(items):
    from functools import reduce
    from operator import add
    assert isinstance(items, list)

    types = {type(item) for item in items}
    if len(types) != 1:
        raise TypeError("All items must have the same type!")
    return reduce(add, items)
```

Output:

```
>>> summer(["a", "b", "c"])
'abc'
>>> summer([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> summer([True, False, True])
2
>>> summer([True, False, "A"])
TypeError: All items must have the same type!
```